# python pandas dataframe from file

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I want to create a dataframe object from a file.  The file looks something similar to this

```
Gibberish Header1
Gibberish Header2
Gibberish Header3
Gibberish Header4 (etc)...
TAG THING_I_WANT_AS_COLUMN_NAME Column1
1.0  # I'll want this index as data 1 
1.2  # I'll want this index as data 2 
1.3  etc
TAG THING_I_WANT_AS_COLUMN_NAME Column2
1.1
1.1
1.7
```

I would want the DataFrame to look similar to:

```
       Column_1    Column_2 
data1  1.0         1.1
data2  1.2         1.1
data3  1.3         1.7
```

Is there a way to do this without writing a function to turn this into a dictionary that can be write directly into the DataFrame class? I was thinking possibly reshape, but I'm not really sure how that would work in my case.  I know writing it to a dict is an easy thing to do, but these files can be quite large, so it might dramatically slow me down and even not be possible with my RAM.

Any help, even a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: No, you will need to write code to transform that into some format that pandas can read directly (like CSV).

Comment: Pre-parse and persist then read it into a ```DataFrame``` - no need  to keep the intermediate product in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a pandas dataframe from scratch I usually do...
    import pandas as pd

```
# create array for each column
col1 = [float(35*x) for x in xrange(10)]
col2 = [float(220*x) for x in xrange(10)]

dict = {'col1_name': col1, 'coll2_name': col2}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Like the other people have said, you'll have to parse the data first. It's hard to say exactly what without seeing the actual data. You could potentially loop over each line in the file, ignore headers, once you hit the line with column name and stuff set a flag. Then you can start appending values to an array. Once you've got both sets of numbers in arrays, build a dictionary like I did up there and you'll have a dataframe!